# How to use expression trees

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am new to expression trees.

Assuming I have a list of Phrase objects, I can generate expressions by calling some functions I have created like this:

```
ParameterExpression peObject = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Phrase), "type");
var qryAnyKeyWord = GetContainsAnyExpression("Description", keywords.ToArray(), peObject);
var qryAuthor = GetEqualsExpression<string>("Author", "jim", peObject);
var qryId = GetLessThanExpression<int>("Id", 4, peObject);
//the above are all binary expressions
```

I can combine the expressions like this:

```
var qryCombined = Expression.AndAlso(qryAnyKeyWord, qryAuthor);
qryCombined = Expression.AndAlso(qryCombined, qryId);
```

And I can compile and use the results like this:

```
Expression<Func<Phrase, bool>> exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Phrase, bool>>(qryCombined, peObject);
List<Phrase> selectedPhrases = phrases.Where(x => exp.Compile()(x)).ToList();

foreach (Phrase p in selectedPhrases)
    show(p);
```

All of this seems to work quite well.

Is there any way to use the expressions in a statement like this:

```
IEnumerable<Phrase> selectedPhrases=
    from p in phrases
    where
    //use "qryCombined" or "exp" here somehow
    select p;
```

Are there other ways of calling the expressions than how I am doing it? Is there a more standard or conventional way?

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Comment: AFAIK: You can't merge Expression Trees, it will always be a Invoke/Call if you use it in a linq statement. This is because the linq statement is generated at compile time, and the expression you created, will be created at runtime.

Comment: Why are you calling `Compile` on your expression?  When you do that you force it to use linq to objects, not linq to some query provider.  If you're going to do that why bother dealing with expressions to begin with?

Comment: @Servy The example shown is just that, an example querying against a list of example objects--there is no provider in this case. As of yet, I have not found a way to get these expressions to work in this instance without calling compile.

Comment: @poolboy Just pass in the expression, as it is, to the `Where` operator.  If the underlying `IQueryable` object is a list or other in memory collection then that's still going to resolve to linq to objects, but when you change the underlying collection it'll still work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to take an `Expression` object that you have and use it in a query expression as the expression for that query operator.  You need to use method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the query partially and then call the extension method that fill apply the expression to filter the data.

```
IQueryable<Phrase> selectedPhrases=
    from p in phrases
    select p;

selectedPhrases = selectedPhrases.Where(CreateFilterExpression());
```

Comment: Your query syntax expression is a noop.  You may as well just remove it.

Comment: He's *already* using the method syntax in the question itself; clearly he already knows how to do that.  He's specifically asking if the expression can be used in query syntax.